# Nothing on screen except for the background picture after logging in

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I was using two monitors last night and now when I turn it on and log in the second monitor is mirrored and nothing is on my desktop.  If I try to open something from the terminal it says it cannot open the display.
Please help!

Comment: I am using sometimes a beamer as second monitor and from time to time it happens the system and I get in dispute about monitor config. Disconnecting the cable to your second monitor will normally reset to default single monitor setup.

Comment: @Requist Even if I disconnect the monitor it doesn't reset =\

Comment: Try deleting the file ~/.config/monitors.xml
(you can do so bu opening a terminal with ctrl-alt-F1 and execute rm ~/.config/monitors.xlm )

Comment: @Requist I did that a day or two ago and no change so far -edit: I'm just going to reinstall Ubuntu and never hook up another monitor again haha, thanks for the help though, you're a peach!

Comment: I am sure there is an other solution for this, but sometimes the drastic approach runs ahead ;)